# Perl operator meaning :: and ->

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and I am wondering what :: and -> mean and if they mean the same or are different? I mostly saw them on variable/method calls on objects? Thanks for any hint!

Comment: *First* start by reading perlop, perldsc, perllol, and perltoot .. I am sure there will be *different* questions after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `::` as in `$main::variable` is a namespace separator; this refers to `$variable` in package `main`. The separator is not an operator at all.

The `->` as in `$variable->{'key'}` is a dereference operator. This is how you refer to the values of a hash which the scalar `$variable` is a reference to (or similarly for references to arrays, with square brackets instead of curlies).

So no, the two constructs are hardly related at all.

Comment: `->` is also used to call methods on objects, which sometimes feels similar to calling subroutines in packages with `::`, but is very different. Read [perlootut](http://p3rl.org/perlootut) for a Perl OO introduction. :)

Comment: of course, it can be `MyPackage::method_name` too, which if its a class method can be called as `MyPackage->method_name` and now they start looking rather similar. I this case the difference is that Perl unshifts either the class name or the instance onto `@_` when using `->`.